# Stanford Relation Extractor custom model selects only one token of relation entities

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I've successfully trained a Relation Extractor model and created a .ser file.

However, I'm running into an issue where the model successfully finds a relation but if one of its entities consists of multiple tokens, **only one token is selected**.
For example, for a relation called *Friend_of*, and a sentence like:

> Sam Tarly's best friend is Jon Snow.

The model will find a relation of type Friend_of between the following entities:

- Tarly
- Jon

This causes my tests to mark this as a **false positive** and the model as a whole to get a bad score.

I've tried training a custom NER model using the same training data, and then using this custom NER model to train the RelationExtractor model with the following properties in my props file:

```
trainUsePipelineNER=true
ner.model=path/to/custom-ner-model.ser.gz
```

But that didn't solve the problem.

Is this just a problem of not enough training data or is there something I'm missing here?

Here is the Java code I use to get the relations:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, depparse, relation");
props.put("sup.relation.model", "lib/custom-relation-model-pipeline.ser");
props.put("pos.ptb3Escaping", "false");

StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);

List<Relation> foundRelations = new ArrayList<>();

for (String doc : documents) {
    Annotation document = new Annotation(doc);
    pipeline.annotate(document);
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class);

    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences) {

        List<RelationMention> relationMentions = sentence.get(MachineReadingAnnotations.RelationMentionsAnnotation.class);

        for (RelationMention relation : relationMentions) {
            foundRelations.add(new Relation(relation.getArg(0).getValue(), relation.getType(), relation.getArg(1).getValue()));
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Simon.

Comment: One answer is if you add the entitymentions annotator it should link "Jon" and "Snow" together into an "entity mention."  When I get more time I can show some sample code for using that info.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667479/how-to-use-entitymentions-annotator-in-stanford-corenlp) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852400/formatting-ner-output-from-stanford-corenlp) similar questions regarding EntityMentionsAnnotator but I'm not sure how to link that to the ie.machinereading.structure.EntityMention instances found in the relation. There is no offset attribute in EntityMention to compare and using indexOf seems wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I looked into the MachineReading relation extraction some more.

I think you want to replace `getValue()` with `getExtentString()` and see if that helps.

I ran on a sample sentence with our default model:

`Joe Smith works at Google.`

And it worked properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to try training the KBPAnnotator with your custom relationship "friend_of".  Then you can use `kbp` instead of `relation` in your pipeline, and kbp has better support for handling full mentions.  When you are done training your model file, you can run the pipeline with `-kbp.model` set to the path where you saved the statistical model.

1.) Study the main method of KBPStatisticalExtractor to see how training is done.

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/KBPStatisticalExtractor.java

2.) I think you need to add your new "friend_of" relationship to the list of known relations in KBPRelationExtractor.java

https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/ie/KBPRelationExtractor.java

3.) You need to put your training data into CoNLL format.  Here is an example sentence that is in the CoNLL training format.  Note how the subject and object of the relation are specified, and note that the first line for the example sentence is "per:employee_of".  Separate all of the sentences in your training data with a blank line.  Note each column is separated by tab.

`per:employee_of
DEE     SUBJECT PERSON  -       -       NNP     PERSON  compound        2
DEE     SUBJECT PERSON  -       -       NNP     PERSON  compound        2
MYERS   SUBJECT PERSON  -       -       NNP     PERSON  ROOT    -1
,       -       -       -       -       ,       O       punct   2
White   -       -       OBJECT  ORGANIZATION    NNP     LOCATION        compound        13
House   -       -       OBJECT  ORGANIZATION    NNP     LOCATION        compound        13
Press   -       -       -       -       NNP     O       dep     13
Secretary       -       -       -       -       NNP     O       dep     13
The     -       -       -       -       NNP     O       det     9
first   -       -       -       -       JJ      ORDINAL nsubj   13
is      -       -       -       -       VBZ     O       cop     13
the     -       -       -       -       DT      O       det     13
US      -       -       -       -       NNP     LOCATION        compound        13
interests       -       -       -       -       NNS     O       appos   2
in      -       -       -       -       IN      O       case    15
Haiti   -       -       -       -       NNP     LOCATION        nmod    13
and     -       -       -       -       CC      O       cc      13
in      -       -       -       -       IN      O       case    19
the     -       -       -       -       DT      O       det     19
region  -       -       -       -       NN      O       conj    13
.       -       -       -       -       .       O       punct   2`

Let me know if you need any more advice or help on this project !

Comment: To provide some context, the `kbp` annotator is the new annotator we have for relations.  The `relation` annotator is older and less has been done to integrate it into the pipeline.  On the other hand, I'm not sure we have great documentation for training new `kbp` models for unique relations.

Comment: I think the `relation` annotator is good enough for now. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I know this should probably be a comment, but I'm not able to commet yet. I've also been trying to train a relation extraction model, but haven't been successful. Is there any chance you'd be willing to share a GitHub repo or more information about how you were able to add a new relation? I'm trying to do almost the exact same thing, but keep getting stuck. Thanks!

Comment: I was about to say that you should post this as a question with all the details but then I saw [you already did](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42497413/custom-relation-extraction-model-using-stanford-core-nlp-doesnt-find-any-relati) and even found a solution. You should mark your own answer as accepted.